# When listing the token on Uniswap for the first time, Which is more effective, V2 or V3?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3

I am studying Uniswap v3. I'm confused about price range setting.
If the token is listed on Uniswap for the first time, there is no transaction record.
so I do not know what criteria(or.. data..?) to set the price range.

When other tokens do an ICO, do they mainly use uniswap V3 to set price ranges? Or do you use v2 to set the full range?

Answer (score 2):

Each of the options has its own merits and drawbacks. For low and mid volume volatile pairs, it’s likely that using Uniswap V2 and setting a full range is the dominant option. On higher volume pairs, you might want to concentrate the range by using Uniswap V3. If you don't have a lot of capital, it's less costly to set price range using Uniswap V2 than Uniswap V3, as adjusting price ranges using Uniswap V3 can accumulate higher gas cost in the long-term.

See:

https://itsa-global.medium.com/defi-insight-concentrated-liquidity-on-uniswap-v3-9dce4e67c3e9

https://www.reddit.com/r/defi/comments/u32812/choosing_a_uniswap_v3_price_range_the_fundamentals/

Comment: Thank you for answer.
Can you let me know ,how do I set the price range to the full range when creating the first liquidity pool with a new token in uniswap V3?
For existing liquidity pools such as ETH/USDC, there is a [Full Range] button in Uniswap v3 UX, but it doesn't seem to be there when i first create a liquidity pool.

Comment: You may need to initialize the pool first before you can set the price range to full range when using Uniswap V3.

Comment: Does "initialize the pool" mean create a liquidity pool regardless of price range and remove it again?

Comment: To initialize the pool means to select a starting price for the pool (e.g, UNI/LINK), then enter your fee tier (e.g., 0.3%), liquidity price range (min. price and max price), and deposit amount. Once that is done, you will see your position under the "Pool" tab. I then click on "+New Position" and select the same pair (UNI/LINK) and select the same fee tier (0.3%) (because this fee tier was created from above). Once selected, I see the "full range" button to the right under "Min Price" and "Max Price".

Comment: when initializing the pool, Can I deposit only a small amount of tokens?

Comment: yes, you can deposit only a small amount of tokens